# Android : How to pass Integer Array between activities?

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I have two activities (Main & Sub) both contain list view to display images. I want to reuse the sub activity for displaying the images according to the cell click in the main activity (some thing like Restaurant Menu). So I have declared an array of integer arrays (Images in drawable folder) that I want to pass to sub activity and the subadapter

I tried below code, but I ended with the Int and Integer conflict.

main activity

```
public class AppsMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView appsmainlist;
    Integer[] images={R.drawable.res,R.drawable.clo,R.drawable.beu,R.drawable.col,R.drawable.tor,R.drawable.hot};
    Integer[][] subarray = {{R.drawable.res1,R.drawable.res2,R.drawable.res3,R.drawable.res4},{R.drawable.clo1,R.drawable.clo2,R.drawable.clo3,R.drawable.clo4}};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps_menu);
        appsmainlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.appsmainlist);
        appsmenuadapter appsmenuadapter = new appsmenuadapter(this,images);
        appsmainlist.setAdapter(appsmenuadapter);
        appsmainlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppsMenu.this,appsview.class);
                    intent.putExtra("subarray",subarray[i]);
                    startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

sub Activity

```
ListView appsviewlist;
Integer [] appsviewarray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appsview);
    appsviewlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.appsviewlist);

// Error goes here
        appsviewarray = getIntent().getIntArrayExtra("subarray");
        appsviewadapter appsviewadapter = new appsviewadapter(this,appsviewarray);
    }
```

Adapter :

```
public class subadapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
...
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: change to primitive int instead of Integer

Comment: if i did so ,  the adapter will not except it !! adapter<Integer>

Comment: create another array and then simply pass values if so, however you can also use adapter constructor for this instead of using generics

Comment: If this is the only functionality of your app, you can have the applications class hold the data, and have the activity retrieve it from the Application class. Another quick and dirty way is to use a static variable in the parent activity, and depending on the design of your app, it may be a safe choice.

Answer (score 2):

Do Arrays keep resource id?
Did you think about to use Resource Array?

Something like this:

`<integer-array name="resoruces">
        <item>@drawable/amex</item>
        <item>@drawable/mastercard</item>
        <item>@drawable/mastercard_white</item>
        <item>@drawable/visa</item>
    </integer-array>`

In this way you can get them using context.

Comment: plz could u direct me to some example ?

Comment: you have subarray to keep array of resources id. So you can use a simple variable `int subarray = 2`, so you can pass it to other activity and you can get correct array. 

`<integer-array name="resource1">..</..>`
`<integer-array name="resource2">..</..>`
`<integer-array name="resource3">..</..>`
 end you can make choice 
`if(subarray==1) context.getIntegerArray(R.array.resource1) ...`

please check correct method name!

Comment: thanks man, works like charm

Comment: Ok! I'm happy to be useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create Bundle and save is as parcelable array